# ARP or LBO in Norway with Telenor

Tags: cellphones, internet, norway

I'm a foreigner and can't speak Norwegian. That's why I thought I'd ask you guys. Someone has to have experience with this? 
This summer I'll fly in from the Netherlands or Germany, depending on where I am at that moment. I'll be staying in Norway for two weeks.

I wanted to know if ARP or LBO works on the Telenor network? I need the Telenor network because it's the only network that has 3G/4G coverage where I'm staying. So any virtual provider on the Telenor network would work just as well.

Comment: I've never sen any advertisements for ARP or LBO in Norway, so I would be pretty sure that these new services are not offered by any providers. You should perhaps also be aware that the deals for prepaid data traffic in Norway are not particularly good. Using Telenor prepaid directly, the data charge is limited to a daily 10 NOK, but you are also limited to 500MB transfer per calendar month. They offer no options to increase the amount of data. I am not aware of other providers with better deals (I've tried to find one though).

Comment: Thank you both! Indeed I found out the same thing about the pre-paid options in Norway. @StewieGriffin Thank you! I'm anxious to hear back from you!

Comment: Followup question: What's your provider today? You're from the Netherlands right?

Comment: My provider in the Netherlands is KPN. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've talked with Telenor. Telenor cooperates with KPN, T-Mobile and Vodafone in the Netherlands. The only answer they could provide was "your current provider should know what possible packages you can have, the prices for data traffic etc". I don't believe ARP or LBO is an option in Norway.

Your best bet is probably [prepaid coverage from NetCom](https://netcom.no/privat/kontant). NetCom are advertising a lot at the moment stating that their 4G coverage is growing fast, thus it might be that where you're going are covered by the time you're there. On the website I linked to, there is a menu on the right hand side with the option "Chat og e-post". If you click this you can live chat with customer service to get more information (they won't have any trouble answering you in English).

I talked to the customer service, and according to them you can buy prepaid packages as long as you register with valid ID. This is an easy access solution as you can buy it at a lot of stores, for instance Narvesen (which you'll find very easily in any city in Norway). Their package with the most data is "Smart Kontant Pluss", which will give you 6GB data for NOK399 (for one month). You'll have to renew if you want to use it for a longer period.

Note that you cannot make international calls, only domestic, thus if you want to call to the Netherlands you'll need two phones, or switch sim-cards back and forth.

You can check out [Telenor](http://www.telenor.no/privat/dekning/dekning_data.jsp) and [Netcoms](https://netcom.no/dekningskart) data coverage maps.

These operators use Telenor's network. You can check out their website and potentially contact customer service.

```
Telenor 
Djuice
Talkmore    
Hello
Xito    
Telipol 
Phonero
Chilimobil
```

Hope this helped!

<sub>FTR: I'm not affiliated with Telenor or NetCom.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! That actually really helped! I'm going to take a look at the virtual providers. At this moment only Telenor has coverage where I'm going, but it may be different in the summer.